# How to use Quick Sort to sort an array of strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I want to use **quicksort** `(std::qsort(arg,arg,arg))` instead of `(std::sort(arg,arg,arg))` to sort an array of strings `s[ ]`.
So  what else do I need to *change* in the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while (t--) {
        char x[1010];
        string s[1010];
        scanf("%s", x);
        int len  = strlen(x);
        s[len] = "";
        for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            s[i] = x[i];
            s[i] += s[i+1];
        }
  //  s[] now contains len number of strings 
        sort(s, s + len);      // So its here where I want to use qsort

    }
    return 0;
}
```

What all the arguments do I need to pass to `qsort(;;)`.**AND** How to write the cmp() function for quicksort.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) helps.

Comment: May be it only works for integers .  I doubt.

Comment: It works for arbitrary types.

Comment: `void qsort( void *ptr, std::size_t count, std::size_t size,
            int (*comp)(const void *, const void *) );` whats the third arg in this case

Comment: It's the compare function to use, in the example in the reference a lambda expression is used.

Comment: There are total 4 in here

Comment: @thorsan isn't it called as string array

Comment: `Despite the name, C++, C, and POSIX standards do not require this function to be implemented using quicksort or make any complexity or stability guarantees.`, just bear that in mind.

Comment: @MarcoA. I want to use only qsort in this case

Comment: There's 3 arguments. The last one is a binary compare function signature.

Comment: @Sparrow -- Using `qsort` on a `std::string` array is not going to work.  It will introduce undefined behavior.  [Please see this](http://ideone.com/v6r0YM).  The `std::string` is not a POD type, and `qsort` is only guaranteed to work on POD types.

Comment: @Sparrow Here is a [better example](http://ideone.com/oIWHVW) of the POD test.  Note that `int` returns "YES".  Please run this program and stick in the type you want to run `qsort` on in the `pod_answer` template before you choose `qsort`.  If you get back "NO", then forget about `qsort`.  You should be using `std::sort` anyway.

Comment: @Sparrow, and one [last example](http://ideone.com/9T9dDh) to show a POD struct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a compare function which compares 2 strings and use that as the last argument in qsort.
read more about the function here 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/?kw=qsort

Comment: If the OP is using `qsort` to sort an array of `std::string`, this may compile, but it is not guaranteed to work since `std::string` is not a POD type.